# Post Json In API error: (500) Internal Server Error. VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, api, post

I use API

To Sending invoices to the tax organization

I have connected to the server, logged in and obtained the token

Define and use these variables

```
Public API As New Net.WebClient
Public response_bytes
Public MyAccecc_Code As String
```

Use This To Login

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         Dim param As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
         param.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials")
         param.Add("client_id", "22ca0891-25bc-455a-b31c-a3a5207c7e10")
         param.Add("client_secret", "b658aed9-b579-4062-b977-17311c42a871")
        response_bytes = API.UploadValues("https://id.preprod.eta.gov.eg/connect/token", "POST", param)
        Dim Mytoken As JObject = JObject.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response_bytes))
        MyAccecc_Code = Mytoken.SelectToken("access_token").ToString
        MsgBox("Done")
End Sub
```

And Use This To Send Invoice

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    API.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & MyAccecc_Code)
    API.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    API.Headers.Add("Cookie", "75fd0698a2e84d6b8a3cb94ae54530f3=7d0b9466d8475676be0c79f8ee9da77d75fd0698a2e84d6b8a3cb94ae54530f3=7d0b9466d8475676be0c79f8ee9da77d;Cookie_1=value")
    response_bytes = API.UploadString("https://api.preprod.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/api/v1/documentsubmissions", "POST", TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response_bytes)
End Sub
```

When using Postman

With the same data, he sends the invoice

When using my software

Gives an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Can See Post man Code here

https://justpaste.it/96ei6

The invoice after turning it into a JSON file

https://justpaste.it/633r2

Please help me I have Deadline to hand invoices

Comment: Well, a response of 500 generally means something has gone wrong at the other end.  Maybe it's caused by the data your send but that's guessing on my part.  Things I would start with, reach out to the api developer to see if they can provide any additional info, and maybe convert to using a httpclient pattern implementation over webclient

Comment: i send same data  by post man  get     202 Accepted

Comment: Your code is generating an error at the api end, so like I said, reach out to them and see if they can give you any help.  I would recommend you use HttpClient rather than webclient, it's a little more robust.  If non of that works, your left with inspecing the actual  request you making including headers/payloads and comparing it to exactly what postman is sending to find the difference

Comment: **  I have not used HttpClient before. Is it possible to convert my code to HttpClient code? **

Comment: Sure it is, have a read over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient

Comment: Won’t guarantee that is the sole fix though,  still could be something in your request payload

Comment: My Project

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XZzgBmE-gTjW7uRxvHpXyECkIBghn1vy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think that same data works on Postman

Comment: Post Man File 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DxveexzUPOIi2Wju3UNbbT_BbZ0F9mDy?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Use `UploadData` instead of `UploadString`

```
response_bytes = API.UploadData("https://api.preprod.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/api/v1/documentsubmissions", "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
```

Comment: Add more details to explain the answer.